# Best way to convert months into Milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to convert a no of months into milliseconds

For example: 
 6 months = X milliseconds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no fixed answer to that, because it depends on which months those are - and indeed which year it is. Also potentially which time zone you're in, if you want to take account of that. (I'm assuming you mean the Gregorian calendar, by the way - different calendar systems have different month lengths.)

You could get some sort of "reasonable approximation" by assuming 365.25 days in a year, and saying that 6 months is half of that, then find out that many days in milliseconds. But it *would* only be an approximation.

For "how many milliseconds does it take to get from date/time X to 6 months later" you'd use an API (even `Calendar` would work for this particular case, although I'd recommend [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) or `java.time` in Java 8):

- Set your start date/time, in the appropriate calendar and time zone
- Fetch the "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" (which is easy enough to retrieve in any API) and remember it
- Add 6 months
- Fetch the "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" again, and subtract the earlier value from it

Comment: +1, and this is why, for instance, the SQL standard has two variants of interval-time: seconds/minutes/hours/days, and months/years. Within each variant, you can meaningfully convert units (if you define a day as 24 hours). But you can't convert from one set to the other.

Answer (score 6):

If you know exactly from when to when those 6 months reach, you can use a variety of ways to calculate the duration, using `java.util.Calendar`, JodaTime, or the JDK1.8 time API.

But if you don't have particular dates in mind, you can take an average duration for your month.
No API in the world can change that fact.

For example, the JDK1.8 time API uses this for the duration of a month in seconds: (from `java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`)

```
MONTHS("Months", Duration.ofSeconds(31556952L / 12)),
```

`31,556,952` is the number of a seconds in a year, based on a year that lasts `365.2425` days.

You can use the same number directly and get the same result as with the time API:

```
long months = 6;
long seconds = months * 31556952L / 12;
long milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
```

Result:

```
15,778,476,000
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar sixMonthsAhead = Calendar.getInstance();
sixMonthsAhead.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
long differenceInMilis = sixMonthsAhead.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
```

You could also use...

```
sixMonthsAhead.add(Calendar.DATE, 180); 
// or 183 days because 365 / 2 is approximately 183.
```

instead of...

```
sixMonthsAhead.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
```

for a more accurate result. But like Jon has mentioned, it will always vary depending on what day of the year it is.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22878506/642706) is correct.

## Joda-Time

Assuming you could specify a pair of beginning and ending points on a time line, here is some example code using the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library.

This code grabs the current moment, adjusts to first of the month, and adjusts to first moment of that day. Then it adds 6 months. Joda-Time is smart about adding the months, taking into account leap year and various lengths of months. This span of 6 months is then represented as an [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) instance. From that we calculate the number of milliseconds. Note that count of milliseconds needs to be a `long` (64-bit) rather than an `int` (32-bit) we Java programmers more commonly use. Lastly, for fun, we see what this span of time looks like when formatted in the [ISO 8601 standard’s "Duration" format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

```
DateTimeZone dateTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ); // Better to specify a time zone than rely on JVM’s default.
DateTime start = new DateTime( dateTimeZone ).withDayOfMonth( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime stop = start.plusMonths( 6 );
Interval interval = new Interval( start, stop );
long milliseconds = interval.toDurationMillis(); // A long, not an int.
Period period = interval.toPeriod();  // For fun… ISO 8601 standard's Duration format.
```

Dump to console…

```
System.out.println("start: " + start );
System.out.println("stop: " + stop );
System.out.println("interval: " + interval );
System.out.println("milliseconds: " + milliseconds );
System.out.println("period: " + period );
```

When run…

```
start: 2014-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
stop: 2014-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
interval: 2014-04-01T00:00:00.000+02:00/2014-10-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
milliseconds: 15811200000
period: P6M
```